# C program that reads in a value and uses it as parameters for a diamond

Tags: c, for-loop

I need to write a program to prompt for an odd positive integer and produce a diamond shape on the page made up of asterisks; the number is the height and also the width...

I am not sure what to do after setting the parameters for odd and positive... I am not quite sure how I can used the `imut` value and set up a **diamond** figure using that value

I have a basic diamond code, but I am not sure what's wrong with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) 
{
    int row, col, numstars;
    int half, rate = 1;

    printf("Please enter a positive odd integer.\n");

    scanf("%d", &numstars);

    for (row = 1; row <= numstars; row++) 
    {
        half = numstars / 2;

        for (col = 0; col < half + 1 - numstars; col++)
            printf(" ");

        for (col = 1; col <= 2 * numstars - 1; col++)
            printf("*");

        if ((numstars == (half + 1)))
            rate = -rate;
        numstars = numstars + rate;

        printf("\n");       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a specific question that we can answer. If the question is "how do I debug my code", you need to tell us what debugger you want to use.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks for the response :D ....uhm any debugger ....I just want to know what I am doing wrong .......

Comment: This could serve as an opportunity for you also to learn good habits to ask for support.  A good start would be to describe what you've done and what's not happening up to your expectations.  Picture yourself in the shoes of the person or persons whom you're asking for help.  And try to realize this is not a "fix my program for me" site.  People here would rather help you learn how to do these things yourself.

Comment: @NoelC Sorry, my bad thanks for the response. I will in the future

Comment: So...  What seems to be the problem?  Does it not compile?  Did you try to run it and it didn't work?

Comment: @NoelC the "specific problem" is that I am not sure where to do after setting the parameters for odd and positive... I am not quite sure how I can used the imut valued and setup a diamond figure using that value :C

Comment: @MarkC Please edit the question to actually ask a specific question then. If you need help coming up with an algorithm, explain what you've worked out so far and ask for help finishing the algorithm. If you have an algorithm and need help coding it, share the algorithm with us.

Comment: Instead of trying to guess how to solve it and printing stars until the sky falls, build your program step by step. Start by printing the number that was entered. Then print that number of stars on *one* row (a row of stars). Then print one star on each row (a column of stars). Then print that number of stars on each row (a square of stars). Then print the number of stars that is the row number (a triangle of stars). Then add spaces according to the row number. Progress the code step by step, until you have it.

Comment: [fix like this ?](http://ideone.com/FAzvG6)

Answer (score 0):

Your asking us here to teach you the basics of algorithm.

- You must be more specific about the problem you have
- You must learn how to debug - extensive resources exist on the Internet, but the easiest is to start with a **beginner book**.

The biggest issue there is, is that you modify `numstar` in your `for` loop... so you obtain an infinite loop...

Here is how I would fix your code: make it simple and distinguish two cases

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int row, col, numstars;
    int half, rate=1;

    printf("Please enter a positive odd integer.\n");
    scanf("%d", &numstars);

    half=(numstars-1)/2;
    for (row=0; row<numstars;row++)
    {
      if(row <= half) {
        for (col=0; col<  half-row;          ++col) printf(" ");
        for (     ; col<= half+row;          ++col) printf("*");
      } else {
        for (col=0; col<  row-half;          ++col) printf(" ");
        for (     ; col<  numstars+half-row; ++col) printf("*");
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```